# Opening another window via Login

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

So I have a login class that basically opens a new window if the login credentials are correct. So I call another class if the credentials are right. Problem is, the window comes up but its empty. Here is the window that I am trying to open. Its pretty basic  as you can see:
(Summary: its just adding some buttons and textfields via grid bag layout and those buttons open up another window)

```
   import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class Library extends JFrame{
        private static JFrame frame;
        private GridBagConstraints padding;
        private JButton addB;
        private JTextField aB;
        private JButton issueB;
        private JTextField iB;
        private JButton holdB;
        private JTextField hB;
        private JButton renewB;
        private JTextField rB;
        private JButton logout;
        private ImageIcon logo;
        private JMenuBar menubar;
        private JMenu file;
        private JMenuItem exit;





        public Library(){
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        }
        //deals with the adding of textfield and label of adding book
        public void addBLabels()
        {
            addB = new JButton("Add Book: ");
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 4;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 0;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(addB, padding);
            aB = new JTextField(30);
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 5;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 0;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(aB, padding);
            event1 butt = new event1();
            addB.addActionListener(butt);
        }
        public class event1 implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    AddBookWindow bookWin = new AddBookWindow(Library.this);
                    bookWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                    bookWin.setTitle("Add Book");
                    bookWin.setSize(500,200);
                    bookWin.setLocation(300,300);
                    bookWin.setVisible(true);
                    bookWin.setResizable(false);

            }
        }




        //deals with issue book labels and textfield
        public void issueBLabels(){
            issueB = new JButton("Issue Book: ");
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 4;
            padding.weightx= 1;
            padding.gridy = 2;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(issueB, padding);
            iB = new JTextField(30);
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 5;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 2;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(iB, padding);
            event2 iss = new event2();
            issueB.addActionListener(iss);
        }
        public class event2 implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    AddBookWindow bookWin = new AddBookWindow(Library.this);
                    bookWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                    bookWin.setTitle("Issue Book");
                    bookWin.setSize(500,200);
                    bookWin.setLocation(300,300);
                    bookWin.setVisible(true);
                    bookWin.setResizable(false);

            }
        }

        //deals with holdbook labels and textfield
        public void holdBookLabels(){
            holdB = new JButton("Hold Book: ");
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 4;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 4;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(holdB, padding);
            hB = new JTextField(30);
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 5;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 4;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(hB, padding);
            event3 hold = new event3();
            holdB.addActionListener(hold);
        }
        public class event3 implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    AddBookWindow bookWin = new AddBookWindow(Library.this);
                    bookWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                    bookWin.setTitle("Hold Book");
                    bookWin.setSize(500,200);
                    bookWin.setLocation(300,300);
                    bookWin.setVisible(true);
                    bookWin.setResizable(false);

            }
        }

        //deals with the renewbook labels and textfield
        public void renewBookLabels(){
            renewB = new JButton("Renew Book: ");
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 4;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 6;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(renewB, padding);
            rB = new JTextField(30);
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 5;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 6;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(rB, padding);
            event4 renew = new event4();
            renewB.addActionListener(renew);
        }
        public class event4 implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    AddBookWindow bookWin = new AddBookWindow(Library.this);
                    bookWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                    bookWin.setTitle("Renew Book");
                    bookWin.setSize(500,200);
                    bookWin.setLocation(300,300);
                    bookWin.setVisible(true);
                    bookWin.setResizable(false);

            }
        }

        //deals with adding the logout button
        public void logOutButton(){
            logout = new JButton("Logout");
            padding.gridx = 5;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 10;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            padding.gridwidth = 1;
            frame.add(logout, padding);
        }

        //deals with adding the image
        public void addImage() throws IOException{
            InputStream imageStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("0521-1005-0822-0024_brunette_girl_smiling_and_holding_a_stack_books.jpg");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageStream);
            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            padding.gridheight = 10;
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
            padding.gridx = 0;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 0;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(picLabel, padding);
        }

        private void menuBar(){

            menubar = new JMenuBar();
            padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            padding.gridx = 0;
            padding.weightx = 1;
            padding.gridy = 0;
            padding.weighty = 1;
            frame.add(menubar, padding);

            file = new JMenu("File");
            menubar.add(file);

            exit = new JMenuItem("exit");
            file.add(exit);
        }


        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
            Library gui = new Library();
            //not working right now gui.menuBar();
            gui.addBLabels();
            gui.issueBLabels();
            gui.holdBookLabels();
            gui.renewBookLabels();
            gui.logOutButton();
            gui.addImage();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setTitle("La Biblioteca");
            frame.setSize(880,430);
            frame.setVisible(true);     
            frame.setResizable(false);
        }
    }
```

Basically in my Login class, my if statement says:

```
if(login credentials are correct)
 Library gui = new Library();
 gui.setSize(880,430);
 gui.setVisible(true);
 gui.addBLabels();
 gui.issueBLabels();
 gui.holdBookLabels();
 gui.renewBookLabels();
 gui.logOutButton();
 gui.addImage();
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556).

The problem is `Library` extends from `JFrame`, but you have ANOTHER `JFrame` as a (`static`) instance field...

```
public class Library extends JFrame{
    private static JFrame frame;
```

When you construct the `Library` class, you are using the `frame` field, but when you set it's properties from are using the `Library` class, you have two different frames.

The solution, don't extend from `JFrame` or any other top level container, ever, you are not adding any meaningful functionality to it and are limiting the re-use of your components.

Instead, consider using a `CardLayout`, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details...

Comment: Ok Thanks! I will check it out. Thing is we never covered this in class.

Comment: @MadProgammer so I looked up card layout and I understand the concept. I am wondering how this would apply to my code. Like for example if the login credentials are right, would I do something like show(mainContainer,"the second window")?

Comment: Not "second window" per say, but "second view" where view is somekind of `Component`

Comment: I asked my professor and he said we can use a GUI editor so I am probably just going to use that, much more easier to use.